# Automatically generate Code Coverage during nightly build

Tags: visual-studio-2013, build-process, code-coverage, nightly-build, runsettings

I have some problems getting the code coverage .coverage file generated in nightly build.

**What I have:** I've configured my build to use a .runsettings file and **Type of run settings** : CodeCoverageEnabled

The build is correctly running all the required unit tests and measuring the code coverage, using only a selected number of assemblies (specified in the .runsettings file).

In the build report, within VS2013, I can *manually* export the code coverage file (a .coverage file).

**What I need:**
I would need to configure the build to *automatically* generate that .coverage file in a target folder.

*How do I do that?*

Answer (score 0):

The .coverage file is present as a part of the test results. You can use the .runsettings to set a outputpath for the test results

```
<ResultsDirectory>c:\\TestResults</ResultsDirectory>
```

The .coverage file will be present in a subfolder within the results directory.

If you want to push it to another location you can do that via a post-build script in your nightly's build process template.

Comment: I tried this:
<RunSettings>
   <RunConfiguration>
      <ResultsDirectory>c:\TestOutputFolder</ResultsDirectory>
   </RunConfiguration>

But the c:\TestOutputFolder contains only the stuff required to run the tests, and not the result.
Did I miss something ?